# How to test tab switch over in WPF application

Tags: wpf, performance-testing

I have one WPF desktop application and I want to test performance of tab switching.

Any suggestions or any tool is available to test this.

Answer (score 1):

Try TabControlAutomationPeer, TabItemAutomationPeer, TabItemWrapperAutomationPeer classes.

This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patrickdanino/archive/2009/11/11/custom-controls-and-ui-automation.aspx) might help you.